# What's this process 'collision'?

Tags: activity-monitor, macos

There's a process running on my machine which Activity Monitor reports is using 142% of CPU, 22 hours of CPU time and has thousands of idle interrupts. It's running under my user, and doesn't appear to be using very much memory.

Does anyone have any notion what this process might be? I've been unable to find anything online, but I can't think what it might be running on my machine. I've got a few Chrome and Safari tabs open, Spotify, and iTerm2 with tmux+vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a super common process name (in my experience at least), so in case no one has a laser-guided answer, some ways to narrow it down:

```
ps auxww | grep -i collision
sudo fs_usage -w collision
sudo lsof | grep -i collision
```

This will show details about where the binary is located on the filesystem, show you in real time the files that process is accessing, and lastly list all open files that the program has.

Hopefully there are some bread crumbs you can follow and you don't have to use `locate collision` or `mdfind collision` to trawl the filesystem to locate the executable file.

Comment: Thanks - I used these commands to track it down to a Go build that was inexplicably indefinitely running. I puzzled over what to do and then just killed it; haven't noticed any ill effects.

Comment: (What's the protocol here - do I add this as its own answer, or mark yours as correct?)

Comment: @JoelAuterson If you're comfortable editing my answer - have at it. If you prefer to answer your way, that's great too! The main thing is to get a check mark indicating it's solved and to have it reflect / educate others. I'd say, document what you found and the steps. Probably simpler than editing mine.